# App freezes few seconds on restart only in development mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

i have problem with starting my app, after restart or change someting in my code - app runs and freeze for 15-20 seconds and then run normally, what its can be a problem ?

I've tried eager loading and its not working..

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 5.2.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
[83835] Puma starting in cluster mode...
[83835] * Version 3.12.1 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
[83835] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
[83835] * Environment: development
[83835] * Process workers: 5
[83835] * Phased restart available
[83835] * Listening on tcp://localhost:3000
[83835] Use Ctrl-C to stop
[83835] - Worker 0 (pid: 83849) booted, phase: 0
[83835] - Worker 1 (pid: 83850) booted, phase: 0
[83835] - Worker 2 (pid: 83851) booted, phase: 0
[83835] - Worker 3 (pid: 83852) booted, phase: 0
[83835] - Worker 4 (pid: 83853) booted, phase: 0
Started GET "/api/v1/aaa" for ::1 at 2019-09-25 10:35:40 +0200
   (3.8ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
  ↳ /Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.0/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
```

Comment: It's a pretty normal behaviour, it needs to reload the code, maybe you can take a look at https://github.com/rails/spring and set it up for your application. Also, might wanna have fewer threads/workers in development. No need to have so many

Comment: In my other aps in rails 4.xx its starts 3-4 sec. here its 20-30sec.. its normal ?